# JavaFX window doesn't show up when I try to get stage property

Tags: java, javafx

I want to get the stage property so I can set `prefWidthProperty` to menu bar in the same window, but whenever I add it to `initialize` method, window doesn't show up even though application is still running and there is no error in output.

**AdminPanelController.java**

```
public class AdminPanelController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private MenuBar adminPanelMenu;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        Stage thisStage = (Stage) adminPanelMenu.getScene().getWindow();
        adminPanelMenu.prefWidthProperty().bind(thisStage.widthProperty());
    }    

}
```

**AdminPanel.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="banking.manager.AdminPanelController">
   <children>
      <HBox fillHeight="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <MenuBar prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="599.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Is there another way to change property of menu on window initialization?

Comment: The scene will be null when `initialize` is called. Don't you get a null pointer exception with this code? The way to make something fill the width of the scene is just to use a layout that sizes it the way you want, possibly with some addition configuration. Can you show the FXML?

Comment: It's added now. Nope, I don't get null pointer exception.

Comment: The only way that fails to give you a null pointer exception is if you explicitly squash all exceptions when you load the FXML.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding all the pref widths? If you just leave those as defaults an anchor the HBox to both sides of the anchor pane, doesn't it do what you want?